# multiple/split class associations in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, object-relational-model

I have the following objects and relations defined. This is actually quite a simple case, and I am providing all those fields just to show why I believe inhalation and injection anesthesia should be defined by two different classes.

```
class InhalationAnesthesia(Base):
    __tablename__ = "inhalation_anesthesias"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    anesthetic = Column(String)
    concentration = Column(Float)
    concentration_unit = Column(String)
    duration = Column(Float)
    duration_unit = Column(String)


class TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia(Base):
    __tablename__ = "twostep_injection_anesthesias"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    anesthetic = Column(String)
    solution_concentration = Column(Float)
    solution_concentration_unit = Column(String)
    primary_dose = Column(Float)
    primary_rate = Column(Float)
    primary_rate_unit = Column(String)
    secondary_rate = Column(Float)
    secondary_rate_unit = Column(String)

class Operation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "operations"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    anesthesia_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('inhalation_anesthesias.id'))
    anesthesia = relationship("InhalationAnesthesia", backref="used_in_operations")
```

I would, however, like to define the anesthetic attribute of the `Operation` class in such a way that any `Operation` object can point to either a `TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia` object or an `InhalationAnesthesia` object.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use inheritance. It's very, very well explained in SqlAlchemy docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/inheritance.html) and [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html#declarative-inheritance)

My recommendation is to create an `Anesthesia` class and make both `InhalationAnesthesia` and `TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia` inherit from it. It's your call to decide which type of table inheritance use:

- single table inheritance
- concrete table inheritance
- joined table inheritance

> The most common forms of inheritance are single and joined table,
>   while concrete inheritance presents more configurational challenges.

---

For your case I'm asuming **joined table inheritance** is the election:

```
class Anesthesia(Base)
    __tablename__ = 'anesthesias'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    anesthetic = Column(String)
    # ...
    # every common field goes here
    # ...
    discriminator = Column('type', String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}
```

The purpose of `discriminator` field:

> ... is to act as the discriminator, and stores
>   a value which indicates the type of object represented within the row.
>   The column may be of any datatype, though string and integer are the
>   most common.

`__mapper_args__`'s **polymorphic_on** key define which field use as discriminator. 
In children classes (below), **polymorphic_identity** key define the value that will be stored in the polymorphic discriminator column for instances of the class.

```
class InhalationAnesthesia(Anesthesia):
    __tablename__ = 'inhalation_anesthesias'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'inhalation'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('anesthesias.id'), primary_key=True)
    # ...
    # specific fields definition
    # ...


class TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia(Anesthesia):
    __tablename__ = 'twostep_injection_anesthesias'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'twostep_injection'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('anesthesias.id'), primary_key=True)
    # ...
    # specific fields definition
    # ...
```

---

Finally the `Operation` class may reference the parent table `Anesthesia` with a typical relationship:

```
class Operation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'operations'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    anesthesia_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('anesthesias.id'))
    anesthesia = relationship('Anesthesia', backref='used_in_operations')
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: So using this set-up I should be able to reference both `InhalationAnesthesia` and `TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia` objects under `Operation.anesthesia`? Would using `Operation.anesthesia = [TwoStepInjectionAnesthesia(..), InhalationAnesthesia(..), Inhalationanesthesia(..)]` mess anything up?

Comment: @TheChymera Yes and Yes. In the example provided an `Operation` instance will reference only one `Anesthesia` object. If you need it to be a list you should change the code a little bit.

Comment: One more thing, what is the advantage of using the above set-up (other than being slightly better organized on the python end)? will the actual sql table that gets generated contain certain column types only for rows with certain discrminators? (thereby saving disk space?)