# Preserve key naming when creating a joinedload sql_query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am extracting a table row and the corresponding row from all referenced tables via SQLAlchemy.

Given the following object structure:

```
class DNAExtractionProtocol(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dna_extraction_protocols'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)
    sample_mass = Column(Float)
    mass_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    mass_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[mass_unit_id])
    digestion_buffer_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    digestion_buffer = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[digestion_buffer_id])
    digestion_buffer_volume = Column(Float)
    digestion_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    digestion = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[digestion_id])
    lysis_buffer_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    lysis_buffer = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[lysis_buffer_id])
    lysis_buffer_volume = Column(Float)
    lysis_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    lysis = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[lysis_id])
    proteinase_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("solutions.id"))
    proteinase = relationship("Solution", foreign_keys=[proteinase_id])
    proteinase_volume = Column(Float)
    inactivation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    inactivation = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[inactivation_id])
    cooling_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    cooling = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[cooling_id])
    centrifugation_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("incubations.id"))
    centrifugation = relationship("Incubation", foreign_keys=[centrifugation_id])

    volume_unit_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('measurement_units.id'))
    volume_unit = relationship("MeasurementUnit", foreign_keys=[volume_unit_id])
```

I am using:

```
sql_query = session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol).options(Load(DNAExtractionProtocol).joinedload("*")).filter(DNAExtractionProtocol.code == code)
for item in sql_query:
    pass
mystring = str(sql_query)
mydf = pd.read_sql_query(mystring,engine,params=[code])
print(mydf.columns)
```

This gives me:

```
Index([u'dna_extraction_protocols_id', u'dna_extraction_protocols_code',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_name',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_sample_mass',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_mass_unit_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_digestion_buffer_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_digestion_buffer_volume',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_digestion_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_lysis_buffer_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_lysis_buffer_volume',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_lysis_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_proteinase_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_proteinase_volume',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_inactivation_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_cooling_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_centrifugation_id',
       u'dna_extraction_protocols_volume_unit_id', u'measurement_units_1_id',
       u'measurement_units_1_code', u'measurement_units_1_long_name',
       u'measurement_units_1_siunitx', u'solutions_1_id', u'solutions_1_code',
       u'solutions_1_name', u'solutions_1_supplier',
       u'solutions_1_supplier_id', u'incubations_1_id', u'incubations_1_speed',
       u'incubations_1_duration', u'incubations_1_temperature',
       u'incubations_1_movement', u'incubations_1_speed_unit_id',
       u'incubations_1_duration_unit_id', u'incubations_1_temperature_unit_id',
       u'solutions_2_id', u'solutions_2_code', u'solutions_2_name',
       u'solutions_2_supplier', u'solutions_2_supplier_id',
       u'incubations_2_id', u'incubations_2_speed', u'incubations_2_duration',
       u'incubations_2_temperature', u'incubations_2_movement',
       u'incubations_2_speed_unit_id', u'incubations_2_duration_unit_id',
       u'incubations_2_temperature_unit_id', u'solutions_3_id',
       u'solutions_3_code', u'solutions_3_name', u'solutions_3_supplier',
       u'solutions_3_supplier_id', u'incubations_3_id', u'incubations_3_speed',
       u'incubations_3_duration', u'incubations_3_temperature',
       u'incubations_3_movement', u'incubations_3_speed_unit_id',
       u'incubations_3_duration_unit_id', u'incubations_3_temperature_unit_id',
       u'incubations_4_id', u'incubations_4_speed', u'incubations_4_duration',
       u'incubations_4_temperature', u'incubations_4_movement',
       u'incubations_4_speed_unit_id', u'incubations_4_duration_unit_id',
       u'incubations_4_temperature_unit_id', u'incubations_5_id',
       u'incubations_5_speed', u'incubations_5_duration',
       u'incubations_5_temperature', u'incubations_5_movement',
       u'incubations_5_speed_unit_id', u'incubations_5_duration_unit_id',
       u'incubations_5_temperature_unit_id', u'measurement_units_2_id',
       u'measurement_units_2_code', u'measurement_units_2_long_name',
       u'measurement_units_2_siunitx', u'dna_extractions_1_id',
       u'dna_extractions_1_code', u'dna_extractions_1_protocol_id',
       u'dna_extractions_1_source_id'],
      dtype='object')
```

This indeed contains all the columns I want - but the naming does not help me select what I want.

Isit possible to preserve the key names from the original table in this dataframe? e.g. instead of `measurement_units_1_code` I would like to have `mass_unit_code`.

Comment: couldn't you rename the columns to suit your need once loaded into pandas?

Comment: That would just offset the issue, I would need to write an explicit mapping (needless to say I am not doing this just for one table), and make sure that `measurement_units_1_code` **always** corresponds to `mass_unit_code` and not to `volume_unit_code`. I am unsure how the number in `measurement_units_1_code` gets assigned, but it would be so much better if I could get the actual key name instead os some number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what `joinedload` is supposed to be used for. You want to do an explicit `join` in this case:

```
session.query(DNAExtractionProtocol.id.label("id"),
              ...,
              MeasurementUnit.id.label("mass_unit_id"),
              ...) \
       .join(DNAExtractionProtocol.mass_unit) \
       .join(DNAExtractionProtocol.digestion_buffer) \
       ... \
       .filter(...)
```

If you don't want to type out all those names, you can inspect the `DNAExtractionProtocol` class to find all relationships and dynamically construct the query and labels. An example:

```
cols = []
joins = []
insp = inspect(DNAExtractionProtocol)
for name, col in insp.columns.items():
    cols.append(col.label(name))
for name, rel in insp.relationships.items():
    alias = aliased(rel.mapper.class_, name=name)
    for col_name, col in inspect(rel.mapper).columns.items():
        aliased_col = getattr(alias, col.key)
        cols.append(aliased_col.label("{}_{}".format(name, col_name)))
    joins.append((alias, rel.class_attribute))

query = session.query(*cols).select_from(DNAExtractionProtocol)
for join in joins:
    query = query.join(*join)
```

**EDIT: Depending on your data structure you might need to use `outerjoin` instead of `join` on the last line.**

You'll probably need to tweak this to your liking. For example, this doesn't take into account potential naming conflicts, e.g. for `mass_unit_id`, is it `DNAExtractionProtocol.mass_unit_id` or is it `MeasurementUnit.id`?

In addition, you'll probably want to execute `sql_query.statement` instead of `str(sql_query)`. `str(sql_query)` is for printing purposes, not for execution. I believe you don't need to pass `params=[code]` if you use `sql_query.statement` because `code` will already have been bound to the appropriate parameter in the query.

Comment: Thank you! How can I inspect my class for all `relationship()` keys?

Comment: @TheChymera I've added an example for that.

Comment: Also, the code above seems to break down if my table uses joined table inheritance (as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869328/multiple-split-class-associations-in-sqlalchemy)).  It seems to be looking in the parent class for keys that are actually provided by the class in question, and crashes with errors like `Tried joining to <class 'common_classes.MeasurementUnit'>, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'protocols' and 'measurement_units'.`

Comment: @TheChymera The relationship inspection code? You need to add some special logic for that. Depending on which tables you need to query, most likely you also need to join the base table. Can you post the entirety of your models, including the ones using table inheritance?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/TheChymera/medaba/blob/4ce5770212e52d276cc486204ec173fb8c2e9111/src/dbdata/common_classes.py) is my full current database model.

Comment: @TheChymera I've fixed the example. In this case, you're not doing anything special with inheritance; there was simply a bug in the original code.

Comment: This now gives me `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: measurement_units.id` how is that ambiguous? And how can I fix this one example? (I'm sure there will be more, but fixable along the same lines)

Comment: @TheChymera That's because you're attempting to join twice to the same table -- once through `mass_unit` and once through `volume_unit`.

Comment: @TheChymera I've updated the example to accommodate that by adding aliases.

Comment: I implemented the newest changes [here](https://github.com/TheChymera/medaba/blob/d2b22ee86c17f8199b0209e879c2317751089bf6/src/dbdata/fmri.py#L49-L67) and the dataframe extracted from the query now contains all of the columns I would be looking for. Sadly for some reason the dataframe is now blank. The SQL query  for the filter seems to be `WHERE protocols.code = :code_1`. I am unsure whether this is correct - shouldn't the filter be the value I store in the `code` variable (which in the current example is `"EPDqEP"`)?.

Comment: Actually, it seems the dataframe is returned empty independently of whether or not I apply a filter.

Comment: @TheChymera You should consider the generated SQL. I don't know what your data looks like. Perhaps you should do an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?